# String to date conversion with format [MonthName] [Day] [Year]

Tags: jquery, momentjs

How do I convert `Sep 2 2016` to date using jquery? Or maybe `moment.js`

Comment: When you say "to date" do you mean to a JavaScript `Date` object, or to something else?  What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with Moment.js you would do the following:

```
moment("Sep 2 2016", 'MMM D YYYY').toDate()
```

This will specify to Moment the intent of the string you are parsing, by using format tokens. After parse, it will return a date object.

If you want this string interpreted as UTC instead of local time, do the following:

```
moment.utc("Sep 2 2016", 'MMM D YYYY').toDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```js
    var str= new Date("Sep 2 2016");
    alert(str.toLocaleDateString("en-GB"));
```